# Android SDK Manager packages missing

Tags: android, eclipse

I would expect to find Google Play Services under the Extras folder. This is missing in my list. How can I download this library?

Comment: If you've already downloaded it, it won't be there unless you check the box to show previously installed packages.

Comment: You might want to post a screenshot of your SDK Manager somewhere and link to it here, so we can see what you are seeing.

Comment: you can install it from SDK Manager, Open SDK Manager , in extras you will be having a list of tools, select GooglePlayServices and install it from their.

Answer (score 0):

I updated the Android SDK Tools to 23.0.2 and Platform Tools to version 20 in the SDK Manager and the Google Play Services entry appeared under Extras.